# get Post data before login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, postdata

We need to catch the login data that have extra information as captcha inputs and more.
When we do login we lost this $_POST information in loginListener so we can't process some data to the database.

The only function that we found to implement some code to access to the database before login and catch some POST data in it, is at the attemptAuthentication function of UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener class, in file:

```
vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener.php
```

But it is core code and we think is a bad practice if we have to modify this.

We need to find a BeforeLogin function and file in Symfony 2 to implement the database access code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a listener for `SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` and get the request from the event object.

Comment: Thanks Kris. Is a good option. 
We tried to implement a onSecurityInteractiveLogin function in LoginListener but it works only after login.
We need to do this before login.
Any idea?